# Framework like richfaces

Tags: php, frameworks, symfony1, richfaces

I worked several years with php in companies with joomla or symfony and they are good framework.
Now, I work with java and jsf/richfaces and it's too a good framework. I like richfaces tags and the time earns with them.

For my personnals projects, I prefer to use php because it's simpler to setup. But I think about that:

Does it exist a php framework which uses a tag system like richfaces ? It'll be very useful to have the flexibility of php and the simplicity of richfaces tags.

I know a plugin for symfony which uses "tags" to create ajax forms or ajax links but it's not the same things.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

im not quite sure how to answer your question, but have you tried symphony-cms.com? its an easy to use PHP CMS that requires almost zero programming knowledge. the templates are XSL, so its made up of simple tags based on the data you want to work with.

Comment: I looked at your cms but it's seem very user oriented. It's look like a cms (like joomla) and no a developper framework (joomla has a framework but it's not the first goal). It's right or I don't understand ^^ ?

Comment: @Kiva actually it has ver little to do with users. Try these tutorials http://see.weareinto.com/3t9R you won't be disappointed, I promise!